# Why is the NSSearchField action is called when changing the sidebar selection?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit, first-responder, nssearchfield

I want to know why is the `NSSearchField` action is called when the sidebar selection has changed? Without changing the search term or even clearing it.

This interferes with the controller logic because I need to load the correct view controller as per sidebar selection. The `NSSearchField` action load the incorrect view controller. If I don't change the sidebar selection, then it is working as intended. But when I do, it interferes. It is quite annoying.

I keep a reference to the `NSSearchField` here.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    var searchField: NSSearchField?
    //...
}
```

Adding the action for `NSSearchField` is done here.

```
extension WindowController: NSToolbarDelegate {
    func toolbarWillAddItem(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let item = notification.userInfo?["item"] as? NSToolbarItem else { return }
        
        if item.itemIdentifier == .searchToolbarItem, let searchToolbarItem = item as? NSSearchToolbarItem {
            searchToolbarItem.searchField.delegate = self
            searchToolbarItem.searchField.target   = self
            searchToolbarItem.searchField.action   = #selector(didStartSearching(_:))
            searchField = searchToolbarItem.searchField
        }
    }
}
```

The method for the `NSSearchField` action is here. The actual implementation is not important:

```
@IBAction func didStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
    print(“This method is called!”)
    //...
}
```

The sidebar's delegate is called in here.

```
extension WindowController: SidebarViewControllerDelegate {
    func sidebarSelectionDidChange(_ sidebarViewController: SidebarViewController, somethingToPass: ModelData) {
        print("Sidebar Has Changed Selection!")
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please. How are the search field, sidebar and content list connected?

Comment: I have edited my question and added some code. I hope this is much more clearer. I used storyboard to build my views.